# Illustrating Newton's Path of Fastest Descent

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, metapost, tikz-graphdrawing

I would like to produce the following Brachistochrone picture in Latex:

[image]

I have searched this site for a Brachistochrone illustration that I might modify and found:

[Coding brachistochrone curve in Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307699/coding-brachistochrone-curve-in-metapost)

After many unsuccessful attempts at modifying the code (though it was the first time I was able to figure out how to even run Metapost code), it decided to post this question. Any help in helping me to produce the first image (preferably Latex which I am familiar with) is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: there are lots of tutorials for Metapost here http://www.tug.org/metapost.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more modern version of my old answer, showing how to draw approximations to the other curves. This is wrapped up in `luamplib` to you need to compile it with `lualatex`.
For more information about Metapost follow [this link](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    pair A, B;
    A = (-1,1) scaled 300;
    B = origin;

    draw A -- (xpart A, ypart B) -- B withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 3/4 white;

    path p[];
    p1 = A -- B;  % line

    % circular
    z0 = (xpart B, ypart A);
    p2 = quartercircle rotated 180 scaled 2 abs (z0-B) shifted z0;

    % parabola f = x^2, f' = 2x
    p3 = A{1,-2} ... (xpart 1/2[A, B], ypart 3/4[A, B]){1,-1} ... B {1, 0};

    % sixth degree f = x^6, f' = 6x^5 
    p4 = A{1,-6} ... (xpart 1/2[A, B], ypart 63/64[A, B]){1, -6/32} ... B {1, 0};

    r = 172; % <- a magic number...
    p5 = (origin for t=5 step 5 until 180: -- (0,r) rotated t shifted ((t/57.29578,-1) scaled r) endfor) 
         shifted A cutafter ((up--down) scaled 10 shifted B);
    

    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);         draw p1; dotlabel.urt("Line", point 1/4 of p1);
    drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 green);       draw p2; dotlabel.urt("Circle", point 1 of p2);
    drawoptions(withcolor 1/4[red, green]); draw p3; dotlabel.urt("Parabola", point 1/2 of p3);
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4[red, green]); draw p4; dotlabel.llft("Sixth degree", point 3/4 of p4);
    drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 blue);        draw p5; dotlabel.urt("Cycloid", point 22 of p5);

    drawoptions();
    dotlabel.ulft("$A$" , A);
    dotlabel.urt("$B$", B);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

*Notes*

- Making the cycloid pass through point B required some trial and error, hence the magic number 172 in the middle. If I can think of a more robust approach I will update this.
- To draw approximations of the parabola and the `x^6` line, I have just picked three points along them and added the appropriate direction syntax `{x,y}` so that the curves are doing in the right direction.  To get more faithful lines you would have to add more points, but I thought that the sketches would be ok here.