# Drawing the circle for a cycloid curve in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Unfortunately I have yet to figure out how to get things done in Tikz and I wanted to ask if someone could help me doing this picture in TeX-Code (Tikz preferably).
I think I could manage to get the circle done but whenever it comes to angles I just screw up massively and I can't figure it out.

[image]

i would highly appreciate any help.
ty very much

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide the code for a complete minimal document showing the bit you can do. Please also avoid abbreviating words texting-style, which makes your post more difficult for those less fluent in English. Are you aware that capital letters are no longer subject to government rationing in most jurisdictions? Also the quotas which previously applied to the use of full stops (periods) and commas have recently been abolished network-wide.

Comment: I'm not aware of a zykloid.  Are you talking about a [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid)?  The wikipedia page also has several equations that can get you started.  Or googling "tikz cycloid" led me to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196957/107497).

Comment: GeoGebra can export TikZ code (though the resulting code can be a bit of a mess, at times).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Removed the calc library and added an animation.

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
 \makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20864/121799
 \newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
    \def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{
        \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{
        \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}
  }
 \makeatother 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,font=\sffamily]
  \draw[-latex] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2.2);
  \draw[-latex] (-0.1,0) -- (2.4,0);
  \coordinate[label=45:{$O$}] (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=45:{$M$}] (M) at (1.1,1);
  \coordinate[label=45:{$T$}] (T) at (M|-O);
  \draw[name path=circle] (M) circle (1);
  \draw[name path=cycloid,green!50!black] (O) plot[variable=\x,domain=0:5*pi/6] ({\x-sin(\x*180/pi)}
  ,{1-cos(\x*180/pi)});
  \path [name intersections={of=cycloid and circle,by={P,Q}}];
  \coordinate[label=45:{$R$}] (R) at (P-|M);
  \tikzAngleOfLine(M)(R){\AngleStart}
  \tikzAngleOfLine(M)(P){\AngleEnd}
  \filldraw[red,fill opacity=0.3]  (M) -- (M)+(\AngleStart:4pt)
   arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:4pt) node[pos=0.3,above,opacity=1]{$t$} -- (M)  --cycle;
  \filldraw[green,fill opacity=0.3]  (R) -- ++(-4pt,0) arc (180:90:4pt) -- (R) -- cycle;
  \draw[name path=line] (T) -- (M) -- (P) node[above,midway,sloped]{$r$} -- (R);
  \node[label=above:{$P$}] at (P){};
  \foreach \X in {O,T,M,P,R}
  {\draw[fill=blue] (\X) circle (0.4pt);}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@@newframe{\@ifstar\@anim@newframe\@anim@newframe}
\def\@anim@newframe{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}
\renewenvironment{animateinline}[2][]{%
  \let\newframe\@anim@@newframe%
  \let\multiframe\@anim@multiframe%
  \begin{preview}}{%
  \end{preview}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
 \makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20864/121799
 \newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
    \def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{
        \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{
        \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}
  }
 \makeatother 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
 \multiframe{62}{i=1+1}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\i/10}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,font=\sffamily]
  \draw[-latex] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2.2);
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (7.2,0);
  \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-0.4) rectangle (7.4,2.5);
  \coordinate[label=45:{$O$}] (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=45:{$M$}] (M) at (\X,1);
  \coordinate[label=45:{$T$}] (T) at (M|-O);
  \draw[name path=circle] (M) circle (1);
  \draw[name path=cycloid,green!50!black] (O) plot[variable=\x,domain=0:0.01+\X] ({\x-sin(\x*180/pi)}
  ,{1-cos(\x*180/pi)});
  % \Disc discriminates between the cases of one and two intersections
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Disc}{ifthenelse(\i>31,1,0)}
  \ifnum\Disc=0
  \path [name intersections={of=cycloid and circle,by={P}}];
  \else
  \path [name intersections={of=cycloid and circle,by={Q,P}}];
  \fi
  \coordinate[label=45:{$R$}] (R) at (P-|M);
  \tikzAngleOfLine(M)(R){\AngleStart}
  \tikzAngleOfLine(M)(P){\AngleEnd}
  \filldraw[red,fill opacity=0.3]  (M) -- (M)+(\AngleStart:4pt)
   arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:4pt) node[pos=0.3,above,opacity=1]{$t$} -- (M)  --cycle;
  \tikzAngleOfLine(R)(P){\AngleStart}
  \tikzAngleOfLine(R)(M){\AngleEnd}
  \ifnum\Disc=0
  \filldraw[green,fill opacity=0.3]  (R) -- ++(-4pt,0) arc (180:\AngleEnd:4pt) -- (R) -- cycle;
  \else
  \filldraw[green,fill opacity=0.3]  (R) -- ++(4pt,0) arc (0:\AngleEnd:4pt) -- (R) -- cycle;
  \fi
  \draw[name path=line] (T) -- (M) -- (P) node[above,midway,sloped]{$r$} -- (R)
  --cycle;
  \node[label=above:{$P$}] at (P){};
  \foreach \X in {O,T,M,P,R}
  {\draw[fill=blue] (\X) circle (1pt);}
 \end{tikzpicture}}
 \end{animateinline}
 \end{document}
```

Using [this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799) one can create an animated gif.

[image]

Comment: (+1) Note that the `calc` library isn't needed, you're not using it.

Comment: wow! thank you so much for this. i really appreciate your help. i will use it immediately and try to get a good grasp of how do do it myself. thank you 1000x

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right (as always;-). I added it before I stole `\tikzAngleOfLine` from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20864/121799), and forgot to drop it.

Comment: @marmot Congratulations.

Comment: @marmot sorry! i didnt know answers can be accepted. thank you for your help :-) i really appreciate it!

Comment: ohhh sorry sorry, i thought i could accept multiple answers - my bad. i just changed it back. this is my very first time on stackexchange. please be patient with me :-)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    calc,
    backgrounds,
    quotes,
    angles,
    }


% 3 couches de dessin
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\tikzset{% Angle droit
    angle droit/.style={very thin},
    angle droit size/.store in=\AngleDtLgth,
    angle droit size=5pt,
    pics/.cd,
    angle droit/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
        code = {%
        \draw[angle droit] ($(#2)!\AngleDtLgth!(#1)$)
        --($(#2)!2!($($(#2)!\AngleDtLgth!(#1)$)!.5!($(#2)!\AngleDtLgth!(#3)$)$) $)
        --($(#2)!\AngleDtLgth!(#3)$) ; ;
        }
    }}


\begin{document}

\foreach \x [count=\n from 0] in {0,5,...,360} {%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-stealth] (-1.1,0) -- (7.5,0) ;
\draw[-stealth] (0,-.5)--(0,2.5) ;
\coordinate (O) at (0,0) ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(\x/180*3.14159,1)}]

\draw[blue, semithick] circle (1) ;

\coordinate (A\n) at (-\x-90:1) ;

\draw[thin] (0,0) coordinate (M) -- (A\n) ;

\draw[red,smooth] (A0) \foreach \p in {0,...,\n} {--(A\p)} ;

\draw[thin,-stealth] (0,-1) coordinate (A) 
    -- (0,1.5) coordinate (B) ;

\draw[thin,dashed] (A\n) -- ($(A)!(A\n)!(B)$) coordinate (R);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw pic[%
    "\tiny\x",
    draw=green,
    fill=green!15,
    angle eccentricity=2,
    angle radius=.2cm
    ] {angle=A\n--M--A} ;
\end{pgfonlayer}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Rangle}{ifthenelse(\x<180,"0","180")}

\foreach \Coor/\Text/\Pos in 
    {O/$O$/225,
    M/$M$/0,
    A/$T$/-45,
    A\n/$P$/225-\x,
    R/$R$/\Rangle%
    } {%
    \draw[fill=blue] (\Coor) circle (1pt);
    \node[shift=(\Pos:6pt),anchor=center] at (\Coor) {\tiny\Text} ;
    }

\path pic[angle droit size=4pt] {angle droit=A\n-R-M} ;


\fill[red] (A\n) circle (1pt) ;

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice!!! (+1) But now I also have to add an animation. ;-)