# How to draw more complicated geometric diagrams

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing

I would like to make diagrams which are a bit more populated than just a circle or a rectangle, and can contain a reasonable amount of information, like this one below:

[image]

But I'm quite inexperienced with tikz, and am unsure how to get the cycloidal arcs AB and AB', for example.

What is the easiest way to generate such a diagram?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are several posts that draw cycloids with Ti*k*Z, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196957/121799.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This draws two boundary cycloids.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
 \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0) (0,2.5) -- (0,-2.5);
 \draw plot[domain=-pi:pi,samples=51,smooth] ({\x - sin(\x r)},{cos(\x r)+1});
 \draw plot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=51,smooth] ({\x - pi - sin(\x r)},{cos(\x r)-1});
 \draw foreach \X in {0.75,1,1.25,1.5}
 {(0,-2+\X) circle[radius=\X]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]